# Convert string which contains symbol of arabic language to const iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, encoding, character-encoding, symbols

I am working on one app in which I need to convert my string which contains the arabic language latter in to const. I have following code but it returns me the nil value.
I tried different encoding style like NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, NSASCIIStringEncodin etc.

my code is as follows.
My string cmpnyname contains the arabic charechter.

```
    const char *textcmnylogo = [cmpnyname cStringUsingEncoding:NSSymbolStringEncoding];
```

textcmnylogo comes nil.

Please let me know the right encoding style.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you resolved the issue then post the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the string in an NSString with the text you need to pick an encoding that can handle the Arabic character(s), `NSUTF8StringEncoding` will handle it as well as other UTF encodings.

Comment: Thanks for reply... i tried NSUTF8StringEncoding but in place of the arabic string it displays the different symbols not the text I have entered.